# How do I uninstall VS code from snap

Tags: linux

I've tried uninstalling it to install it again to start from scratch but it's not working.
I used `sudo snap remove code` and `sudo snap remove code --purge`. But once I install it again everything is there, every extension. everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Clean uninstall# If you want to remove all user data after
> uninstalling VS Code, you can delete the user data folders Code and
> .vscode. This will return you to the state before you installed VS
> Code. This can also be used to reset all settings if you don't want to
> uninstall VS Code.
>
> Linux - Delete $HOME/.config/Code and ~/.vscode.

Comment: I'm on Garuda Linux and can't seem to find the code and .vscode folders